# Saying Siri to open my app is not working

Tags: iphone, siri

I've checked that **Siri** opens third party apps such as Facebook, and I'd like to be able to open my ios app with siri as well.

I've tried saying the name of my app but it doesn't seem to work and I don't find any examples or documentations for this.

Do I need to add some code in my app to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: I didn't do anything to get it working with my apps. Are you sure you are saying it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on pronunciation and language ascent also. Everyone speaks with an accent. You may speak English with an accent from a different region in the United States. You may speak English with an accent because English is not your first language. So it could be problem in your case.
I’ll try that but it doesn’t working after that process
[image]